# Retrieve State From Redux Store

Tags: react-redux

I am learning Redux global state store and I created a simple app, when click the "Select" button, the selected item will be added to the SavedCourses list. Then I want to display the SavedCourses list. But right now my code does not display the list. Is there something wrong with my reducer? My [sandbox link](https://ky801.csb.app/#/) is  at https://ky801.csb.app/#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually your `mapDispatchToProps` function which is the problem.  `addCourse` is supposed to take an argument which is the `class_nbr`.  But your `this.props.addCourse` function ignores its arguments and just calls `dispatch(addCourse())`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addCourse: () => dispatch(addCourse())
  };
};
```

Since you aren't actually passing the course info, your `savedCourses` is ending up like `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

---

You could change your `mapDispatchToProps` so that it takes an argument:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addCourse: (class_nbr) => dispatch(addCourse(class_nbr))
  };
};
```

But when all you are doing is dispatching the function with the same arguments then it is not necessary to define `mapDispatchToProps` as a function. You can just [use an object of action creators](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object):

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addCourse})(Courses);
```

---

Redux has gotten a lot easier nowadays with the [react-redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) and [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/).  You can simplify your code a lot using those.